# Access text from UITextField in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing a UITableViewController which have 3 sections among first two contains 2 and 1 text field respectively. I am having problem in accessing the text input in text field. I have no idea how to fix this issue in iOS swift please help.

In table view controller

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let gender = Gender(rawValue: indexPath.row)

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            guard let nameCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addNameCellID") as? ChildFormViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            nameCell.firstNameField.text = "" // just in case cells are re-used, this clears the old value
            nameCell.firstNameField.tag = indexPath.row
            return nameCell

        case 1:
            self.tableView.rowHeight = 50
            guard let dateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addDateCellID") as? ChildFormViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            return dateCell

        case 2:
            guard let genderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addGenderCellID") as? ChildFormViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            genderCell.genderLabel.text = gender?.nameString()
            return genderCell

        default:
        return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

extension AddChildFormTVC: ChildFormViewCellDelegate {
    func getFirstName(text: String?) {
        print(text)
    }
    func getLastName(text: String?) {
        print(text)
    }
    func getDateOfBirth(text: String?) {
        print(text)
    }
    func getGender(text: String?) {
        print(text)
    }

}
```

---

```
class ChildFormViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var lastNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dateField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var genderLabel: UILabel!
    var delegate: ChildFormViewCellDelegate!


}

extension ChildFormViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        switch(textField) {
        case self.firstNameField:
            self.delegate.getFirstName(firstNameField.text)

        case self.lastNameField:
            self.delegate.getLastName(lastNameField.text)

        case self.dateField:
            self.delegate.getDateOfBirth(dateField.text)

        case self.genderLabel:
            self.delegate.getGender(genderLabel.text)

        default:
            return
        }
    }
}

protocol ChildFormViewCellDelegate {
    func getFirstName(text: String?)
    func getLastName(text: String?)
    func getDateOfBirth(text: String?)
    func getGender(text: String?)
}
```

Comment: Wen you say 'accessing' the text, do you mean at cell generation, or do you mean outside of the UITableView Delegate methods? i.e. refer to a particular textField in the UITableView to get it's text?

Comment: No I want text whenever the user enters text in the text field.

Comment: Do you mean, when the users enters text, as he presses a key, you get a callback sending a message at every keypress e.g. typing in `hello` would result in 5 callbacks, each returning `h`, `he`, `hel`, `hell`, `hello` or just after the user is done i.e. a callback with the full `hello`?

Comment: I want result when user is done typing i.e one callback with full hello.

Comment: so is your textFieldDidEndEditing getting called?

Comment: Add UITextFieldDelegate and firstNameField.delegate = self and so on...

Comment: No  textFieldDidEndEditing is not called as I amn't able to make TableVIew or TableViewCell as delegate of textField

Answer (score 0):

Then try:

```
    //This will call back after focus is lost from the input    
self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateFirstName), forControlEvents: .EditingDidEnd)
    //This will call back with every change, i.e. each letter
self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateFirstName), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

Also, where `self` is added as the target, `self` means the `UITableViewController`. As far as I know, an object can't be it's own delegate. It'd be pointless if that were possible.